# Vue.js: Inline if-else statement inside <form> with multiple conditions

Tags: if-statement, vue.js, nested, conditional-statements

Is there a way to make inline if-else statement with multiple conditions in Vue?

I have this code in vue:

```
<template>
  <div class = "modal-dialog">
    <div class = "modal-header"> <h5>Header</h5></div>
     <div class="modal-body">
       <form @submit.prevent="editMode ? updateParticipant() : addParticipant()">
          /* actual form inside modal body */
       </form>
     </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

However, I have another boolean variable `queryMode`. So, I want to also check its value before I execute the methods. More of a nested statement like this:

```
if(editMode) {
  if(queryMode) { 
     updateParticipant();
  } else {
     //another method
  }
} else {
   addParticipant();
}
```

I have searched about `v-if`, `v-else-if` and `v-else`, but I don't know how to integrate them in my current code structure.

Comment: Why not just have a single handler method than contains code very similar to the `if`/`else` structure you posted in the question? You could make things hard to read with nested ternaries but it seems unnecessary to do all of this inline.

Comment: I tried to do that.. `editMode` and `queryMode` variables are declared as return variables with a value, `false` by default. But when I console.log their current values inside a method, it doesn't log anything at all. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have a single handler:

```html
<form @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
```

with:

```js
methods: {
  onSubmit () {
    if (this.editMode) {
      if (this.queryMode) { 
        this.updateParticipant();
      } else {
        //another method
      }
    } else {
      this.addParticipant();
    }
  }
}
```

You could, in theory, write it all inline but it would be difficult to read:

```html
<form @submit.prevent="editMode ? queryMode ? updateParticipant() : anotherMethod() : addParticipant()">
```

You could put some parentheses in but that wouldn't be much better.

Comment: Oh no!! Now I know why the single handler method doesn't work. I forgot to execute `npm run watch`. I knew there's something's weird. Haha! Now everything works!